# Submit Ajax Loaded Form Elements Along with Non-Ajax Loaded Form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have some form elements, but then at the user's will, they can load in some other form elements via ajax (i.e. advanced search, etc.)  I want to load them via ajax because there is a category section that is rather heavy with a lot of categories and I would rather not always load them into the page unless they are absolutely needed.

However, when the other AJAX loaded form elements are added, they are not visible in the source code and when I submit the form, they are not being included with the other original HTML items even though they are theoretically within the form tags. IF I place the inputs directly within the ajaxforms div instead of loading them in via AJAX and submit, they do get passed with the form and show up in the following pages URL parameters.

So, maybe I need to use Jquery (it's what I am familiar with, but I am happy to use JS if I can sort it out) to also submit these hidden Ajax loaded inputs?  Or maybe, I am using the wrong method to insert them?

The form needs to be submitted directly and not in the background via ajax as the next page uses the $_REQUEST to parse various data.  I welcome any alternative ways of doing this if this seems less than ideal for some reason.

HTML

```
 <form action="/Search.html" name="SearchForm" id="SearchForm" method="get">

 <div id="main">
 <input type="text" name="mainformitem">
 <img src="/ajaxforms.gif" id="ajaxformbutton">

 <div id="ajaxforms">
 <!-- AJAX FORM CONTENT WILL BE LOADED HERE -->
 </div>

 </form>
 </div>
```

The Jquery to load in the extra forms.

```
   //LOAD IN THE EXTRA FORMS
    $(document).ready(function(){

   //Drop Down Advanced Form Options onclick

   $("#ajaxformbutton").click(function(){       

       $( "#ajaxforms" ).load( "ajaxforms.php" );

   })  
 });
```

My Attempt at submitting the ajax induced form data along with the HTML form data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#SearchForm').on("submit", function(event) {

   // stop the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();

    // get data in the inputs of the form
  var data = {};
  var inputs = $('#SearchForm').children("input, select, textarea");
  inputs.each(function($element){
  console.log($element);
  data[$element.attr('name')] = $element.val();

  });

  // submit all forms
$('#SearchForm').submit(data);
});
});


 </script>
```

Comment: If you don't want the ajax form elements from being submitted with the form; why not just append them outside the form?

Comment: Your statement "they are not visible and therefore not submitted with the original form." does not make any sense. Visibility has nothing to do with submitting. If you append them to the form, as you seem to do, they WILL be submitted.

Comment: I would suggest leaving the form as is (do not attach your "onsubmit" handler), and see via firebug what actual variables get posted.

Comment: @pkExec Maybe I am not saying the right thing... But...  If I simply copy the content from my page that I am loading in via ajax and place it directly within the #AjaxForms div, and click to submit, the input items are submitted and show up in the URL on the next page showing me that they have been submitted.

If, however, I load them in via AJAX, I see them in the browser, but I don't see them within the HTML source code.  And when I click to submit, they are not submitted with the form and do not show up in the URL on the following page.  Thanks!

Comment: @shuskic I do want them submitted.  That is the goal of this question.  Currently when I load them in via ajax, they are not submitting along with the other HTML form items.  They show up in the HTML, but they aren't getting passed.  Thanks!

Comment: This is confusing me as on this example, the LOADED items ARE showing up in the source HTML: http://api.jquery.com/load/#entry-examples

So, why are mine not there when I look at the source?

Comment: Can you include what your php returns *exactly*? I just ran a quick test and what you're describing should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Change this :

```
 $('#SearchForm').on("submit", function(event) {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#SearchForm', function(event) {
```